# Tunnel Connection Error with Mysql Workbench (Host key does not match)

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with Mysql Workbench which is probably a bug.

I'm using EC2 with elastic IPs. I changed my server, but kept my keypair and IP the same. So it should connect as usual via SSH tunnel.

When I try to connect via Mysql Workbench, it says:

> Tunnel connection error. 
>   Host key for server 00.00.000.000 does not match!
>   Delete entries for the host from the 
>   C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming...\known_hosts file

The problem is, the known_hosts file does not exist on my system. I tried reinstalling MySQL workbench, but the uninistall does not eliminate the file, apparently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it! The file was here:

> C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\ssh

Comment: Hidden Windows folders are NO fun!

Comment: 'ssh' file does not exist with Workbench 8.0.16. The folder %appdata%\MySQL\Workbench\ does exist, but does not contain file or folder _ssh_

Answer (score 3):

You can find this file in .ssh folder in the `%USERPROFILE%\ssh` or  `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`. If you type `%USERPROFILE%` into the Windows Explorer address bar it will expand it automatically.

OR you can open this folder using "run" dialog box. Open run dialog box (windows + R). Type **`%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`** and press enter.

And then delete/clear the `known_hosts` file.